# How Data Access Layer (and Database) which are in remote JVM (server) communicate with web app which is in local JVM?

Tags: java

How Data Access Layer (and Database) which are in remote JVM (server) communicate with web app which is in local JVM?

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with "web app". Normally a webpage (read: HTML/CSS/JS/etc) doesn't run on JVM, unless you have embedded an Applet or JNLP. A JSP/Servlet webapp just runs at the server machine, generates/produces a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS/etc and sends it to the client side. The client doesn't need a JVM to be able to visit a Java webapp.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [RMI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html) ? Without knowing your requirements it's difficult to comment. RMI will certainly be a simple solution to Java client/server communication.

Comment: In webapps you really don't want to use RMI between webserver and webclient (webbrowser). There you have HTTP for. Maybe the OP is talking about communication between webserver and databaseserver, but still then, there you have JDBC for. It's all quite confusing, apparently the OP didn't get the concepts right and that's also why I posted the comment on his question.

Comment: @Balus, Brian is not suggesting RMI between browser and webserver. The question seems to be about communication between different servers.

Comment: When the OP say "webapp in local JVM" I can imagine that he actually meant the webbrowser. I've seen this misconception often enough. Don't underestimate ignorance.

Comment: I also don't second-guess requirements unless I explicitly say so. I'm *not* sure what the OP wants, hence my caveat in the second sentence.